# Hooking into woocommerce login form not possible

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hook into woocommerce login form so that I can add a class to form element like this:

```
<form class="my-custom-class">
```

but apparently there is no way to do that. 
I can hook into checkout form (before) with this action hook:
woocommerce_before_checkout_form

But for hooking into registration form, I couldn't find a way around it.

Is it possible to hook into resitration form or even "User info editing form"?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't hook into the form...you should simply override the **form-login.php** partial template.

To do this:

1. Copy `woocommerce/templates/auth/form-login.php` to `yourtheme/woocommerce/auth/form-login.php`
2. Make the changes to the form's `class` attribute.

Read more about overriding WooCommerce templates [in the docs](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: Thank you, I knew that we could do that but I was looking for a hook for that purpose. I think it's best to alter woocommerce views trough hooks and not by altering the template files.

Comment: It depends on the situation...there is no "best". This kind of functionality can only be altered by modifying the template. There is no hook for it.

Comment: Thank you so much rnevius and sorry for the delay.